# Where is to edit the firewall-rules for iptables and ip6tables correctly?

Tags: scripts, iptables, firewall

I want to set myself up the rules for firewall in iptables. But several queries have delivered different file-locations for iptables-rules.

One location is in /usr/local/bin and there is to create file with name fwall-rules as script ?! - But this looks antique ...

Other location is to create file apparently in /etc with name of script iptables.rules ?! (as explained in: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo)

Where is today fwall-rules to be edited in 18.04 for iptables ?

Are the fwall-rules then included in iptables automatically - or do I need to create a link for this in terminal for Ubuntu ?

When I write as command:

> sudo ip6tables -I INPUT -s fe80::b131:5a4d:9ebf:4c36 -j DROP

Where is this then saved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to bother with file locations as long as you use either UFW or iptables commands to change the firewall rules.

Ubuntu now has [UFW - Uncomplicated Firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) - that works as a wrapper for iptables and that makes it easier to enable the firewall and to edit rules. By default, the UFW is turned off and must be turned on with

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Rules are added with a simple *allow* or *deny*, for example:

```
sudo ufw allow <port>/<optional: protocol>
```

Both ports/packets and services can be allowed or denied. See the reference above for details on rules.

For more complex hardware setups - for instance several NICs on the same box - foregoing the simplicity of the UFW and editing iptables directly may be adviseable. This is set out in the How To you referred to: [Iptables How To](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo?action=show&redirect=Iptables).

Comment: You mean command iptables and ip6tables is not used any more ? - But these commands are still active ?

Comment: Yes, @dschinn1001, you can use either one or the other, but UFW is simpler and usually sufficient, unless you have a complex NIC setup.

Comment: ... the thing is, that some Adresses ignore my Commando as typed below in my question.

Comment: address fe80::b131:5a4d:9ebf:4c36 is still active - how can I block this with success ?! ip6tables command is somehow ingnored ? ...

Comment: What is the output of sudo ip6tables -S and sudo ip6tables -L
?

Comment: BTW: If you use iptables, iptables-persistent is an easy way to make iptables rules persistent, see also [How to make iptables rules persistent after reboot on Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-make-iptables-rules-persistent-after-reboot-on-linux)

Comment: wait please for displaying the output of your mentioned commands ... iptables-persistent does not exist as command ? ... for ip6tables not too ? ...

Comment: the dropped ip-addresses are not listed in ip6tables -S and not listed in ip6tables -L - it seems that they are "unreachable" ... yeah clear, because the blackhat is faking ips and hides himself behind 0.0.0.0 (as faking address too). Cannot post the output here ... - to big. Have now read the link you gave in comment. thx.